# How to get Json string from document.viewData using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, xmlhttprequest, viewdata

I'm trying to grab & parse a json string that's returned when making an HTTP GET call to webpage that provides my user stats. The problem is, the response isn't a json response (because the site doesn't have a public api). Instead, it's a plaintext/html response; however, I noticed when I'm authenticated/logged into my account (which I always am) the first lines on the html response are `script` tags as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.viewData = {"current_filter":"active","current_filter_title":"Active Gigs","dds":{"timeRange":{"current":{"text":"Last 30 days","val":30},"options":[{"text":"Last 7 days","val":7},{"text":"Last 30 days","val":30},{"text":"Last 3 months","val":90},{"text":"Last 6 months","val":180}]}},"popups":{"statuses":{"title":"What does your Gig\u003csup\u003e\u0026reg;\u003c/sup\u003e status mean?","statuses":[{"label":"Active","label_class":"Active","explanation":"Your Gig is visible and may be ordered by all users."},{"label":"Draft","label_class":"Draft","explanation":"You need to finish editing your Gig before it goes live."},{"label":"Paused","label_class":"Paused","explanation":"No one can see your Gig. You may reactivate it whenever you like."},{"label":"Denied","label_class":"Denied","explanation":"This Gig failed to pass our review and is not visible to anyone."},{"label":"On Hold","label_class":"On Hold","explanation":"This Gig is disabled due to inactivity. You can reactivate it later."},{"label":"Pending Approval","label_class":"Pending Approval","explanation":"Gig is pending Fiverr's review and is not yet available."},{"label":"Express","label_class":"Express","explanation":"Express Gig. You must deliver it within 24 hours."},{"label":"Featured","label_class":"Featured","explanation":"Your gig was handpicked by Fiverr and will get higher exposure."},{"label":"Attention","label_class":"Attention","explanation":"Your Gig requires some modifications before it goes live."}]}},"results":{"rows":[{"type":"my-gigs-tr","is_child_gig":false,"dropdown":{"attrs":"style=\"margin-top: 5px;\"","autowidth":true,"noContent":true,"noUppercase":false,"pullClass":"pull-right","label":{"text":"","attrs":""},"options":[{"text":"Preview","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"//www.fiverr.com/michaelhill24/create-an-excel-template-to-suit-your-needs\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Preview\""},{"text":"Edit","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-template-to-suit-your-needs/edit\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Edit\""},{"post":true,"text":"Pause","attrs":"action=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-template-to-suit-your-needs/suspend\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Suspend\""},{"text":"Share","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"/michaelhill24/create-an-excel-template-to-suit-your-needs?arrived_from_manage_gigs=true\u0026display_share=true\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Share\""},{"post":true,"text":"Delete","attrs":"action=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-template-to-suit-your-needs/delete\" class=\"delete-gig-form js-delete-gig-form js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Delete\""},{"text":"Add Video","attrs":"href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-template-to-suit-your-needs/edit#gig-edit-upload-video\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Video Action\""},{"text":"\u003clabel class=\"fake-check-grey check-text\"\u003e\u003cinput name=\"portfolio[69580532]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"0\" /\u003e\u003cinput checked=\"checked\" id=\"portfolio_69580532\" name=\"portfolio[69580532]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"chk-img\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003eLive Portfolio\u003c/label\u003e","attrs":"href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-template-to-suit-your-needs/toggle_work_samples\" class=\"portfolio js-edit-portfolio\""}]},"gig":{"id":69580532,"status":"approved","prev_status":null,"path":"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-template-to-suit-your-needs/edit","image_src":"https://cldn0.fiverrcdn.com/fiverr/t_small_thumbnail/gigs/69580532/original/f8e23aeff6388bcc362411685624384ccb74d56a.jpg","title":"create an excel template to suit your needs","traffiqed":false},"gigsData":[{"type":"impressions","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"clicks","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"page_views","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"orders","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"cancellation_rate","value":0,"trend":null}]},{"type":"my-gigs-tr","is_child_gig":false,"dropdown":{"attrs":"style=\"margin-top: 5px;\"","autowidth":true,"noContent":true,"noUppercase":false,"pullClass":"pull-right","label":{"text":"","attrs":""},"options":[{"text":"Preview","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"//www.fiverr.com/michaelhill24/create-formulas-for-your-spreadsheet\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Preview\""},{"text":"Edit","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-formulas-for-your-spreadsheet/edit\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Edit\""},{"post":true,"text":"Pause","attrs":"action=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-formulas-for-your-spreadsheet/suspend\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Suspend\""},{"text":"Share","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"/michaelhill24/create-formulas-for-your-spreadsheet?arrived_from_manage_gigs=true\u0026display_share=true\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Share\""},{"post":true,"text":"Delete","attrs":"action=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-formulas-for-your-spreadsheet/delete\" class=\"delete-gig-form js-delete-gig-form js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Delete\""},{"text":"Add Video","attrs":"href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-formulas-for-your-spreadsheet/edit#gig-edit-upload-video\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Video Action\""},{"text":"\u003clabel class=\"fake-check-grey check-text\"\u003e\u003cinput name=\"portfolio[69580997]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"0\" /\u003e\u003cinput checked=\"checked\" id=\"portfolio_69580997\" name=\"portfolio[69580997]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"chk-img\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003eLive Portfolio\u003c/label\u003e","attrs":"href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-formulas-for-your-spreadsheet/toggle_work_samples\" class=\"portfolio js-edit-portfolio\""}]},"gig":{"id":69580997,"status":"approved","prev_status":null,"path":"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-formulas-for-your-spreadsheet/edit","image_src":"https://cldn0.fiverrcdn.com/fiverr/t_small_thumbnail/gigs/69580997/original/a0e23a26389c486f169970ba8425c667bc88f36b.png","title":"create formulas for your spreadsheet","traffiqed":false},"gigsData":[{"type":"impressions","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"clicks","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"page_views","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"orders","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"cancellation_rate","value":0,"trend":null}]},{"type":"my-gigs-tr","is_child_gig":false,"dropdown":{"attrs":"style=\"margin-top: 5px;\"","autowidth":true,"noContent":true,"noUppercase":false,"pullClass":"pull-right","label":{"text":"","attrs":""},"options":[{"text":"Preview","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"//www.fiverr.com/michaelhill24/sort-and-organize-your-excel-data\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Preview\""},{"text":"Edit","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/sort-and-organize-your-excel-data/edit\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Edit\""},{"post":true,"text":"Pause","attrs":"action=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/sort-and-organize-your-excel-data/suspend\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Suspend\""},{"text":"Share","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"/michaelhill24/sort-and-organize-your-excel-data?arrived_from_manage_gigs=true\u0026display_share=true\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Share\""},{"post":true,"text":"Delete","attrs":"action=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/sort-and-organize-your-excel-data/delete\" class=\"delete-gig-form js-delete-gig-form js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Delete\""},{"text":"Add Video","attrs":"href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/sort-and-organize-your-excel-data/edit#gig-edit-upload-video\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Video Action\""},{"text":"\u003clabel class=\"fake-check-grey check-text\"\u003e\u003cinput name=\"portfolio[69580262]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"0\" /\u003e\u003cinput checked=\"checked\" id=\"portfolio_69580262\" name=\"portfolio[69580262]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"chk-img\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003eLive Portfolio\u003c/label\u003e","attrs":"href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/sort-and-organize-your-excel-data/toggle_work_samples\" class=\"portfolio js-edit-portfolio\""}]},"gig":{"id":69580262,"status":"approved","prev_status":null,"path":"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/sort-and-organize-your-excel-data/edit","image_src":"https://cldn0.fiverrcdn.com/fiverr/t_small_thumbnail/gigs/69580262/original/e8538f7ed52f530867b714d046725100aa87c996.png","title":"sort and organize your excel data","traffiqed":false},"gigsData":[{"type":"impressions","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"clicks","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"page_views","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"orders","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"cancellation_rate","value":0,"trend":null}]},{"type":"my-gigs-tr","is_child_gig":false,"dropdown":{"attrs":"style=\"margin-top: 5px;\"","autowidth":true,"noContent":true,"noUppercase":false,"pullClass":"pull-right","label":{"text":"","attrs":""},"options":[{"text":"Preview","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"//www.fiverr.com/michaelhill24/create-macros-for-your-spreadsheets\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Preview\""},{"text":"Edit","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-macros-for-your-spreadsheets/edit\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Edit\""},{"post":true,"text":"Pause","attrs":"action=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-macros-for-your-spreadsheets/suspend\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Suspend\""},{"text":"Share","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"/michaelhill24/create-macros-for-your-spreadsheets?arrived_from_manage_gigs=true\u0026display_share=true\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Share\""},{"post":true,"text":"Delete","attrs":"action=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-macros-for-your-spreadsheets/delete\" class=\"delete-gig-form js-delete-gig-form js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Delete\""},{"text":"Add Video","attrs":"href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-macros-for-your-spreadsheets/edit#gig-edit-upload-video\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Video Action\""},{"text":"\u003clabel class=\"fake-check-grey check-text\"\u003e\u003cinput name=\"portfolio[69576742]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"0\" /\u003e\u003cinput checked=\"checked\" id=\"portfolio_69576742\" name=\"portfolio[69576742]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"chk-img\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003eLive Portfolio\u003c/label\u003e","attrs":"href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-macros-for-your-spreadsheets/toggle_work_samples\" class=\"portfolio js-edit-portfolio\""}]},"gig":{"id":69576742,"status":"approved","prev_status":null,"path":"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-macros-for-your-spreadsheets/edit","image_src":"https://cldn0.fiverrcdn.com/fiverr/t_small_thumbnail/gigs/69576742/original/056f20c7e0eee9f37141ce18d7c486a75481f0f5.jpg","title":"create macros for your spreadsheets","traffiqed":false},"gigsData":[{"type":"impressions","value":"4","trend":"pos"},{"type":"clicks","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"page_views","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"orders","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"cancellation_rate","value":0,"trend":null}]},{"type":"my-gigs-tr","is_child_gig":false,"dropdown":{"attrs":"style=\"margin-top: 5px;\"","autowidth":true,"noContent":true,"noUppercase":false,"pullClass":"pull-right","label":{"text":"","attrs":""},"options":[{"text":"Preview","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"//www.fiverr.com/michaelhill24/create-an-excel-add-on-for-your-company-9825a82c-e51b-4193-ba1a-f6536b5ecf0b\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Preview\""},{"text":"Edit","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-add-on-for-your-company-9825a82c-e51b-4193-ba1a-f6536b5ecf0b/edit\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Edit\""},{"post":true,"text":"Pause","attrs":"action=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-add-on-for-your-company-9825a82c-e51b-4193-ba1a-f6536b5ecf0b/suspend\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Suspend\""},{"text":"Share","attrs":"target=\"_blank\" href=\"/michaelhill24/create-an-excel-add-on-for-your-company-9825a82c-e51b-4193-ba1a-f6536b5ecf0b?arrived_from_manage_gigs=true\u0026display_share=true\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Share\""},{"post":true,"text":"Delete","attrs":"action=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-add-on-for-your-company-9825a82c-e51b-4193-ba1a-f6536b5ecf0b/delete\" class=\"delete-gig-form js-delete-gig-form js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Delete\""},{"text":"Add Video","attrs":"href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-add-on-for-your-company-9825a82c-e51b-4193-ba1a-f6536b5ecf0b/edit#gig-edit-upload-video\" class=\"js-gtm-event-auto\" data-gtm-category=\"My Gigs\" data-gtm-action=\"Gig Action\" data-gtm-label=\"Video Action\""},{"text":"\u003clabel class=\"fake-check-grey check-text\"\u003e\u003cinput name=\"portfolio[69578892]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"0\" /\u003e\u003cinput checked=\"checked\" id=\"portfolio_69578892\" name=\"portfolio[69578892]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"chk-img\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003eLive Portfolio\u003c/label\u003e","attrs":"href=\"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-add-on-for-your-company-9825a82c-e51b-4193-ba1a-f6536b5ecf0b/toggle_work_samples\" class=\"portfolio js-edit-portfolio\""}]},"gig":{"id":69578892,"status":"approved","prev_status":null,"path":"/users/michaelhill24/manage_gigs/create-an-excel-add-on-for-your-company-9825a82c-e51b-4193-ba1a-f6536b5ecf0b/edit","image_src":"https://cldn0.fiverrcdn.com/fiverr/t_small_thumbnail/gigs/69578892/original/46dccc4883906f2cf287b9964358244ac7c52303.png","title":"create an Excel Add On for your company","traffiqed":false},"gigsData":[{"type":"impressions","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"clicks","value":"1","trend":"pos"},{"type":"page_views","value":"1","trend":"pos"},{"type":"orders","value":"0","trend":null},{"type":"cancellation_rate","value":0,"trend":null}]}]},"haveTranslations":false,"show_nested_sub_cat_banner":false,"denied_gigs_alert":null};
</script>
```

The value inside the `document.viewData` object is the json string that I need in order to parse the information I'm looking for (gig stats). How can I access this string that's stored in the `document.viewData` using javascript? I know how to parse a json string using javascript, I just don't know how to get the string out of the `document.viewData` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse that with a regex applied to the whole page HTML:

```
document.viewData = ([^\n]+)
```

The first group in the regex will contain the json string.